# Правильність утворення дієприкметників із закінченням -мий

Tags: словотворення, дієприкметники

Чи можливо використовувати закінчення *-мий* для утворення пасивних дієприкметників? У словниках зафіксовані слова **значимий**, **любимий**, а чи можна, наприклад, від слова **воліти** утворити слово **волимий**?

Comment: Такий суфікс очевидно є (_(с)відомий_, _знайомий_, _рухомий_). Але очевидно, що не до будь-якого кореня можна застосувати будь-який суфікс — і мова не лише про «за змістом не підходить», а банально про традицію — не звикли вживати певну комбінацію, та й по всьому. (Хоча є слова «на межі», які вживаються, але рідко, або не вживаються, але їх можна легко ввести в ужиток.) «Волимий» я _ніде_ не бачу, думаю, такого слова немає. Але загальне правило (коли можна вживати такий суфікс, а коли — ні), я, на жаль, не можу сформулювати.

Comment: Радше було б "вол**і**мий" (голосна зберігається). В деяких телевізійних каналів спостерігається наполеглива тенденція до створення нових слів.

Comment: https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/значущий/

Comment: Коли ми перекладали [Вступ до алгоритмів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вступ_до_алгоритмів), то редактор кривився коли почали вживати *допустимий* як переклад *feasible*. Я так розумію, що він уважав оце *-мий* як щось не дуже українське і волів би його замінити, але ми не знайшли на що.

Comment: А чому *-мий* звучить як щось неукраїнське? Хіба можна якимсь чином пояснити недоречність його вживання та існування в українській мові? Щодо **волімий** замість **волимий**, то, попри відсутність цього слова в українській мові, я гадаю, що з погляду словотвору правильний варіант — саме з уживанням *-имий*. Як приклад наводжу слово **незгоримий**, утворене від слова **горіти** — тут, як на мене, **незгорімий** звучало би незграбно та неприродно. Але слово **незгоримий** не зафіксовано у словниках, хоч і зустрічається в деяких літературних творах.

Comment: У будь-якому разі, **волімий** не може існувати — від **терпіти** існує словникове й широковживане **терпимий**. Тож теоретично буде **волимий**.

Comment: @ІлляЯндовський Може. "Волимий" з И зовсім не звучить на відміну від І. Можливо, справа у попередній приголосній. Ще це повязано з тим, що, коли ми утворюємо нове (неіснуюче) слово (яке можна буде взяти в лапки і використати), воно має бути максимально наближеним до оригіналу, інакше його сенс буде важко ідентифікувати (що я спостерігаю у даному випадку) - з И я б його не зрозумів у реченні.

Comment: Я не зміг знайти жодного дієприкметника в українській мові, що б закінчувався на *-імий*. Натомість є два слова, які мають закінчення *-лимий*: **неопалимий** і **невмолимий**. Дієслова, від яких вони утворені, закінчуються на *-ити*, а не *-іти*, як у разі зі словом **воліти**. Проте, якщо сказати **неопалімий**, це, як на мене, також не виглядатиме неприродньо, хоч і звичайно, це не є правильним варіантом. Видно, звукосполучення *лі* сприймається природніше мовцями, тому в спірних питаннях йому радше надають перевагу, хоча бачимо на прикладі **терпіти**, що після *-іти* все одно йде *-имий*.

Comment: "Неопал**і**мий" і "терп**і**мий" дійсно не звучать, на відміну від "вол**і**мий" - бо ця голосна одразу ж натякає на значення цього слова. А "вол**и**мий" немов пов’язано з волами.

Answer (score 2):

Спонуканий обговоренням в коментарях до запитання написав пану Кувалді:

> Маю до вас запитання. Коли ми перекладали розділ про лінійне
> програмування, то ми переклали feasible region/solution як допустима
> область / допустимий розв'язок. Але вам тоді оце допустимий не
> сподобалось. Я так розумію через -мий. Але чому? Це не відповідає
> українському словотвору?

Відповідь пана Кувалди:

> Не то щоб зовсім не відповідав, такі слова є в українській, але вони
> не поширені і така форма не продуктивна. І зазвичай є паралельні форми
> кращі.
>
> > [Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р.](https://r2u.org.ua/html/shel_pered.html) (І.
> > Шелудько, Т. Садовський)
> > **Допускаемый** – допускни́й, припускни́й.
> > **Допустимый, допускаемый** – допускни́й, припускни́й.
>
> > [Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р.](https://r2u.org.ua/dicts/hanitkevych)
> > (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш)
> > **допуска́емый** допустни́й [прийня́тний], припускни́й
>
> До того ж гляньте, як перекладає [слова на *-ble* Кочерга](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=*ble%20&dicts=4&highlight=on). Тож я за
> послідовність і нові тенденції [від -тимий віє старослов'янщиною
> [тобто староболгарщиною] як на мене].

Зауважу, що тут йдеться про *-тимий*, тому, можливо, нема зв'язку з *волимий.*

РЕД: Доповнення від пана Кувалди:

> Щодо *волимий*. Формально такі слова можна утворювати. Але як кожен новотвір він буде незвичним. Крім того, ми можемо настворювати слів до біса, які не матимуть ужитку. Ліпше залежно від контексту вживати близькі за значення, *бажаний*, *жаданий*, *призволений*.

Comment: По-перше, слушна заувага щодо староболгарщини. По-друге, я вважаю, що зв'язок між *-тимий* і *-лимий* та іншими формами присутній, адже деякі мовці сприймають усі ці форми як дещо неприродне в контексті української мови. Але для слова **воліти** без закінчення *-мий* я не бачу паралельних форм, тільки **волимий** звучить більш-менш. Гадаю, що за відсутності інших підхожих форм можна використовувати *-имий* з метою утворення пасивних дієприкметників.